# How do you get end-points on an ecdf curve using plotly in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly, ecdf

I am trying to create a cumulative distribution function as a plotly object using ggplot2 and converting it using ggplotly, but the tails for 0 and 1 get lost in the conversion. How can I get the lines to extend to 0 and 1 using plotly in R?

This is the code I'm using:

```
gg <- ggplot(data=some_data, aes(x = x_var, color = grouping_var)) +
stat_ecdf()

ggplotly(gg)
```

This is the ggplot I get

[image: ecdf with ggplot]

But when I turn it into a plotly object the tails disappear and this is what I get

[image: ecdf after conversion to plotly]

Edit: Editing to incorporate Quinten's request for recreation data:

```
new_data <- iris %>%
arrange(Petal.Length)

gg <- ggplot(data = new_data, 
             aes(x = Petal.Length, 
                 color = Species)) +
      stat_ecdf()

ggplotly(gg)
```

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I don't have access to share the data I used but I think it can be recreated using R's built in dataset: 

```
new_data <- iris %>%
arrange(Petal.Length)



gg <-
ggplot(data = new_data, aes(
x = Petal.Length,
color = Species
)) +
stat_ecdf()



ggplotly(gg)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is the way that plotly handles the infinite x axis values produced as default by `stat_ecdf`. Although this can be turned off with `stat_ecdf(pad = FALSE)`, this just leaves your initial ggplot without the endpoints too.

We can replicate your problem, as you suggested in the comments, with the iris data set:

```r
library(ggplot2)

new_data <- iris %>% 
  arrange(Petal.Length) 

gg <- ggplot(data = new_data, aes( x = Petal.Length, color = Species )) + 
      stat_ecdf()
```

In native ggplot, everything looks OK:

```
gg
```

[image]

But in plotly we miss the 0% and 100% lines because they stretch off to minus and positive infinity and are therefore dropped:

```r
ggplotly(gg)
```

[image]

The way round this is to make the ecdf ourselves over a fixed range (say, 0 to 7). This requires a little data manipulation:

```r
xmin <- 0
xmax <- 7

gg2 <- new_data %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(y = sapply(seq(xmin, xmax, 0.1), function(x) ecdf(Petal.Length)(x)),
            Petal.Length = seq(xmin, xmax, 0.1)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Petal.Length, y, color = Species)) +
  geom_step()
```

Now our ggplot looks like this:

```r
gg2
```

[image]

And the plotly version remains faithful to this:

```r
ggplotly(gg2)
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your answer Allan, I played around with it a bunch, but the problem I'm facing with this solution is it assumes a normal distribution which might not be the case and the resulting plot is not an ecdf anymore.

Comment: @Chezaire sorry - you were right about it not being an ecdf - it should have been divided by the length of the input vector (now corrected and updated using the ecdf function for vlarity). I don't know what you mean about assuming a normal distribution - there are no assumptions about the distribution at all, and this method should work for any data. If you are struggling to apply it, could you edit your question to include data, and show how it doesn't work?